# Validator Message attribute in <h:inputtext> is not showing the message in xhtml using i18ntext file

Tags: jsf

I have done the below code to display validation message for restricting character length.Validation message has been given in the i18ntext file with label key.

```
<h:inputText id="details" maxlength="255"
             validatorMessage="#{bundlepageView['Label.length-description']}"
             value="#{page.description}"/>
```

in i18ntext file, I have provided message.
in UI,  no message is displaying. please help

Comment: Where is your `h:message` component to display the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error messages are not shown by the component that they were created for. You need to add a `h:message` component to show the error. In the `for` attribute you should put the client ID of the component you want to show the error for, so:

```
<h:inputText id="details" ... />
<h:message for="details" />
```

To show all the errors (for any component), use:

```
<h:messages />
```